# How to read specific parts of a input file in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have an input file with the following data:

```
50 50
A
B
C
D
```

I know that I can extract the first line using the map function as follow:

```
x,y= map(int, input().split())
```

But I am unsure how I can retrieve the next 4 lines and put them into a list. I tried using the splitlines() function, since each value is on a seperate line, but that only returns the first value.

```
strings = input().splitlines()
```

How can I choose what parts of the input file I want to read and then store them in respective variables?

Comment: `input()` function is used with console inputs, not files. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are multiple files, each with a different set of inputs. I need to take into account all these files, which is why I can't specify a filename.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, read all the lines into a list, do what you want with them

```
with open("[filename]", "r") as f:
    lines = list(map(lambda l: l.strip(), f.readlines()))

# do whatever with the lines here
# use lines.pop(0) if you want to remove the line from the list
```